# WordPress Child CSS Conflicts with Parent

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Only certain styling in my child theme's stylesheet is being applied to my site, while other stylings are being ignored and my parent theme's styling is being applied. Any ideas?

**child theme's functions.php**

```
<?
   add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 
   'senorpicoculinary_child_and_parent_stylesheets');

function senorpicoculinary_child_and_parent_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'parent-style',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/stylesheet.css'); 

    /* For the child style, I didn't use get_directory_uri() because
       that seems to point to style.css, and our styling file is stylesheet.css*/
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/stylesheet.css'); 
}
?>
```

**Parent Theme functions.php**

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 
        'generic-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 
      'favicon',
      get_template_directory_uri().'/favicon.ico');
  wp_enqueue_style( 
        'bootstrap',
    get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 
        'megamenu-stylesheet',
        get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/megamenu.css');  
  wp_enqueue_style( 
        'webfont-kit',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css'); 

  wp_enqueue_style( 
        'tv-style',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/stylesheet.css');  

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
?>
```

**Child Theme CSS:**

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'momoco_inlineinline';  //doesn't work
    color: blue; //works
}

body {
    background-color: black; // doesn't work
  }
```

**Parent Theme CSS** (all applied instead of my child theme's styling)

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
  font-family: AvenirLT-Roman;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
body {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: AvenirLT-Roman;
}
```

Comment: Use the [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rule?

Comment: can you check if your child css being loaded before your parent theme?

Comment: Is there a way I can check, Toan? I thought since my child theme is loaded after my parent theme in functions.php, it would load in the correct order.

Comment: based you enqueue, it should be so. You can check on Network tab of Inspector to see which file being loaded first.

Comment: Looks like the parent theme 's stylesheet.css is loaded after the child's stylesheet.css. But why? I have it loading before my child theme's in functions.php.

Answer (score -1):

I will let you know in advance that this is widely regarded as NOT the best practice, but I and many web developers do it.
Use !important to force certain attributes.

For example:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'momoco_inlineinline' !important;  //this will work ;)
    color: blue; //works
}

body {
    background-color: black !important; // this too :)
  }
```

Ideally, you would want to find what's causing this to happen, and maybe change your workflow.

Comment: I'm hesitant to do that just because if I have to do it for these basic cases, I'm going to have to add "!important" to every single thing I change in this stylesheet.

Comment: It's just a basic problem on specificity, using `!important` on these cases will break down the whole cascading things.

Comment: Sooo how did you solve the problem? `!Important` whether or not we like using it, especially when you don't have time to debug, is very IMPORTANT, pun intended. Just a suggestion, that is still widely used.